# Making faster jQuery AJAX post

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

How can I make jQuery ajax post that connecting to a php file more faster? Could I enable some caching? Here are my codes

```
$.post("return.php",{"t": "editpost"},function(sResult)
    {
        switch($.trim(sResult))
        {
            case "success":
            {

            };break;

            case "error":
            {

            };break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: How long does it take now? How fast do you want it to be?

Comment: There are many network-related factors at play here, the least of which are code-related.

Comment: there's nothing in the code you posted that has anything to do with the speed. You'd need to show the 'return.php' code that runs as that's likely where the problem lies.  As for the caching, you could change to a `$.get` (if possible) so the browser caches the results (`$.post` is not cached)

Comment: If you are sending multiple requests at the same time, and you are using sessions, make sure you close the session (with session_write_close()) as early as possible, otherwise each request will wait for the previous to finish before being processed.

Answer (score 0):

add return false at the end of the function